# How can Conditional assembly work on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, assembly, preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I want to reuse some assembly code on Xcode, like nasm conditional assembly does:

.macro My_function 1

```
.globl function_$0_neon

function_$0_neon:

 #ifdef SAD
 vadd.u8 q0,q1
 #else
 vsub.u8 q0,q1
 #endif

 bx lr
.endm

#define SAD

My_function SAD

#undef SAD

#define SATD

My_function SATD

 #undef SATD
```

I expect two macro will be extend separately in a file once. 
It passed compile but doesn't work, #idefine also fails. Any suggestion or Apple spec about this? Thanks!

Comment: Thank your suggestion, but I don't sure how to accept the best?

Comment: Just click the check outline near the best answer - see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask